# Exterior product of a differential form and its derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\omega$ be a k-form on a smooth manifold $M$ such that there exists $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ with $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in M$ and $d(f \cdot \omega)=0$.

I need to show that $\omega \wedge d\omega =0$.

I have only been able to show that $\omega \wedge d\omega =\frac{1}{f} \omega \wedge \omega \wedge df$ but I don't know how to conclude.

Comment: What is $\omega \wedge \omega$?

Comment: @Max: Be careful. Only when $k$ is odd are you going to conclude something. :)

Comment: Oops! Well I guess half is better than nothing...

Comment: if $\omega=w(dy\wedge dz+du\wedge dv)$ and $f(y,z,u,v,w)=w^{-1}$ ($M$ is say $\mathbb R_+^5$) then $\omega\wedge d\omega\neq0$

Comment: @at user8268: fantastic! Please convert your great  comment to a genuine answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** this only works when $k$ is odd. (Thanks Ted Shifrin for pointing this out).

Use the Leibniz rule to expand $d(f\omega)$, then wedge with $\omega$. Finally, use the fact that $f$ is nowhere zero and that $d(f\omega)=0$ (In particular that $\omega \wedge d(f\omega) =0$).

**EDIT 2:** This is false in general: Take $M=(0,\infty)$, $f$ any nonconstant smooth function on $M$, and $\omega=1/f$.

Comment: This is pretty much what I have done to show that $\omega \wedge d\omega =\frac{1}{f} \omega \wedge \omega \wedge df$: $d(f\omega)=df \wedge \omega +f d\omega$ thus $d\omega=\frac{-1}{f} df \wedge \omega$. What else can I find doing that ?

Comment: Don't use that $d(f\omega)=0$ until the very end.

Comment: I really don't get it sorry. If I do $\omega \wedge d(f\omega)=\omega \wedge (df \wedge \omega +f d\omega)= \omega \wedge df \wedge \omega + f \omega \wedge d\omega=0$, I get exactly the same thing as I got before.

Comment: See my edit. I made a crippling mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I already managed to conclude when $k$ is odd. Does anyone know if the statement is even true if $k$ is even ?

Comment: See my new edit.